Unsolicited application for a job while the managing director propably wants to take on the role in personal union
Background:
Almost three years ago, a manager position was advertised for which I would have very much liked to apply. At that time, however, I decided against applying for personal reasons mostly but also because of insecurities. In hindsight, however, I really regret this decision! My company has been holding out the prospect of further development for me for years, but nothing concrete has ever been announced, only individual personnel development measures.
Semi recent:
A few months ago, I was told that I am offered to take over a team leader position in about two years' time, as the previous manager will be retiring. I am familiar with the role and I feel comfortable with the tasks, but it is not my dream job, especially not in comparison with the one I mentioned earlier.
I accepted the non-binding offer, but after a few days I spoke to the managing director again to explain to him that I was grateful for the opportunity and felt up to the task, but that, unlike the other position that had been filled in the meantime, it was not my dream. During this conversation, I also found out that the managing director had been expecting my application for the first position and that he had indicated that I would have been given this if I had applied. He also said something along the lines that opportunities arise more than onece in life if you are patient and that I still have a few years of working life ahead of me.
If I had known at the time of the job advertisement that my application would have been welcome, I would have put my private/family concerns aside . I thought a lot about what hints I might have overlooked but over all I found my peace with the past and am not bitter about my decission because it was the best one possible given all information.
Now:
Now I've heard through the grapevine that the current holder of my dream job is leaving at the end of the year. But there is no official news about this. At the same time, I've heard that the managing director wants to take over his position in personal union. He has been very unhappy with the job holder's work in recent years.
Now I'm afraid of letting another chance slip by. On the one hand, I recently expressed my interest in the position and learned that he considers me suitable. On the other hand, the team is under a lot of pressure due to the failures of the last few years and I can imagine that the managing director therefore wants to make it a top priority to turn the team around himself. Finally, it may also play a role that I am supposed to take over another position whose activities I am familiar with. Finding a replacement here will bring its own challenges for the company.
On the one hand, the information is only a few weeks old, on the other hand, the rest of the year is not long either:
Does it make sense to bring oneself back into the game in such a mixed situation without being asked? If so, how can you make your enthusiasm clear without being too intrusive? On the one hand, the information is only a few weeks old, on the other hand, the rest of the year is not long either:

Does it make sense to bring oneself back into the game in such a mixed situation withoutbeing asked?
If so, how can you make your enthusiasm clear without being too intrusive?


Just ask.
It always pains me to see how much opportunity and potential job satisfaction gets squandered just because people don't say what they want. Contrary to common believe many managers are perfectly willing to tailor (to the extent possible) assignments, positions, and development to the employee's preferences, since it's a win-win. But they can only do it if you TELL THEM WHAT YOU WANT. They are not mind readers.
You might get a "yes", you might get a "no". But if you don't ask you'll never get anything.
So in your case, just can have a quick meeting with the hiring manager and say something like:

Hi. I've been thinking about my career development and I would really like a role similar to XXX because of YYY. I think I would be good at it because of ZZZ. So I was hoping when something comes up in your department along these lines, that you would give me the opportunity to take a shot at it. I would also welcome any feedback you may have on what I could do to become a better candidate for this type of roles. Thanks

Most hiring managers really like this approach, since it gives them an idea what they have to work with. If they don't want you, they can just ignore it: No harm done. If you are a suitable candidate, you just fast tracked your path to the next role.

... I decided against applying  ...  but also because of insecurities.

Time for a little bit of introspection here: In my opinion any job title with the word "director" in it requires the ability to speak up for your team and your function. If you can't speak up for yourself, how would you be able to do this for others? By not applying you (rightfully) disqualified yourself from the job. You may want to work at this a bit (if you haven't already).

Now I've heard through the grapevine

Stop that. No more rumors, no more grapevine. If you want to do or know something, just ask directly. More often then not rumors are plain wrong or sometimes even based on malicious intent.

Does it make sense to bring oneself back into the game in such a mixed situation without being asked?

Yes, absolutely. Needing to be asked will disqualify you from most leadership positions. It is the exact opposite of leadership.

If so, how can you make your enthusiasm clear without being too intrusive?

By asking in a way that's friendly, honest, open and not demanding. The key is to give the other person the option to say "no" without feeling bad about it. That also requires you to become emotionally comfortable with a "no" yourself.

This is good advice. While I'm still an overthinker I today feel much moe confident in my skills and knowledge. I often tried to shift my perception of the decission from three years ago from missed opportunity towards 'I needed more experience and confidence. I was no ready back then'.

Glad to hear that you made progress and are ready for the next step: Go and get it! Good luck.

+10 Great answer
